# What is wrong using this keyword in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, this

I am asking this question due to [mKorbel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel)  second comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577125/inserting-a-row-into-a-resulttablemodel-as-well-as-database). I have been using `this` keyword to call local variables, local components of that class (example Buttons) and methods e.t.c. I am not sure what is wrong with using the keyword the way I have been doing it.

> *don't to use this.whatever in Swing, Java, (in MCV make me some sence), use local variables insted of.*

**Question:** What is wrong with using `this.XXX` in Swing?

**Sample Code**

```
public class SwingTest extends JFrame {

// variables
private String st = "You clicked me";

SwingTest() {
    this.initUI();

}

private void initUI() {
    this.setTitle("Swing Test");
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);

    this.clickMe = new JButton("Click"); // What is wrong with using this
                                            // ref here?

    this.add(clickMe);

    this.clickMe.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, this.st);// What is wrong with
                                                        // using this ref
                                                        // here?
        });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwingTest swingTest = new SwingTest();
        }
    });
}

// components
JButton clickMe;
}
```

Comment: Nothing, but it is redundant as `this` is generally assumed.

Comment: He maybe meant that you should have a `private final JFrame f = new JFrame();` inside your `SwingTest` rather than extending `JFrame`... But only he can tell...

Comment: if you remove `this.` then also that code will work, because compiler implicitly pass `this` reference to instance methods and constructors

Comment: Okay, I thought it might be something related to **performance issues**.

Comment: @Prashant Yes I know that; that is why I asked if I should let the compiler do it for me.

Comment: @Giovanrich It makes no difference performance wise.

Comment: search for inheritance v.s. composition in Java, Swing, by default this idea is valid for all programing languages, not just for Java

Comment: @ssylias good and right point about local variable, instead of hunting for reference of Objects, especially in GUI should be system, this.Xxx can be misspelled on 1st exception in GUI (right and correct inherites from essential classes)

Comment: @mKorbel Very well I now understand what you mean. I have seen the reason [here](http://thebadprogrammer.com/2012/08/swing-composition-vs-inheritance/) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button clickMe does not need to be a field. It can be a local variable `JButton clickMe` inside the dialog defining method/constructor. As normally many GUI components are created and added to the window, it cleans up the class, keeps declarations close to usage, and leaves the life-time as short as possible (on changing window contents).

(The talk about `this` is merely to point out the fieldness of `clickMe`.)